# Binding combobox selected value to a specific column of current row (not a datagridview)

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I have a database that I am using in a VB 2010 project. What I did was removed a textbox for a database field that I dragged onto the form and replaced it with a combobox. The field name was `orderstatus`.

The problem is this: since I removed the textbox field from the form, I can't seem to bind the combobox value to the field in the active record. In other words, `orderstatus` textbox doesn't exist anymore. I want to let the user pick a status from the combobox and store that value to orderstatus so that it's saved to the current record my database.

I want to do something like this:

```
Private Sub Button16_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button16.Click
  orderstatus = ComboBox13.SelectedValue
  Me.OrdersDataSet.orders(0).orderstatus = orderstatus
  Me.Validate()
  Me.OrdersBindingSource.EndEdit()
  Me.TableAdapterManager12.UpdateAll(Me.OrdersDataSet)
End Sub
```

but it doesn't like my second line where I try to assign the value to the field, saying there is no row 0. All I want to do is put the selected value of the combobox into the orderstatus field of the record being created (or updated).

I've also tried using:

```
Me.OrdersDataSet.orders.orderstatusColumn = orderstatus
```

and I get a message saying that the property of the column is ReadOnly. I'm not sure how that's possible because I configured the dataset to update, etc.

I should probably mention that I'm not using a datagridview but a details view, if that makes a difference. I've seen some talk about how to do this using datagridview and don't know if that would work in my case.

What am I doing wrong? What should I use to update just the column I want in the current row?

Comment: "but it doesn't like my second line where I try to assign the value to the field." is there an exception, or...?

Comment: I'm getting "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference." However, I thought that assigning a field's contents went something like what I have if it has more than one row. I've been mostly dealing with one row databases lately lol.

Comment: You need to see why orderstatus is not instantiated. I assume it is declared as `Friend WithEvents orderstatus As datasetname`, but the forms designer should also have `Me.orderstatus = new datasetname` inside `InitializeComponent()` to create an instance.

Comment: I'm not seeing that. So even though I have a table adapter and binding source, take away a field textbox, how can I reference that field in the row of the record being created or edited? I updated my code to show one way and I'm getting an error that says there's no row 0. When I do a check with the ID field, it shows -1 when I click my "add new" record button (I'm entering the first record.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, turns out I had forgot to set the databinding properties of the field in question to save directly to the binding source and also select the selecteditem to bind. It was right there and I didn't realize. Ya live and learn. :)